# Pandas custom function

Tags: python, pandas, function, custom-function

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| Cust_ID | PROD_ID | Quantity | Price | Quantity | Price | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 31-12-2020 | 31-12-2020 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 |
| 123 | abc | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5.4 | 11 | 6 |
| 123 | efg | 50 | 53 | 50 | 53 | 100 | 53 |
| 456 | abc | 10 | 5 | 10 | 5.4 | 10 | 6 |
| 456 | efg | 10 | 53 | 10 | 53 | 11 | 53 |

Columns are double indexed with the first two rows shown bellow (date+ Price/quantity).
I want for each date (after 31-12-20) to create a new column that calculates the following:

IF quantity is different with the previous day then new column contains 0 on this row.
ELSE new column contains (date Quantity * date Price) minus(-)  (previous date Quantity * previous date Price)

I have created a for loops but that iterates the data frame for each date but takes too long.
How can I create such a function to apply?
PS Indexes are reliable but column order may differ.

Answer (score 0):

First, here is a clean version of your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('123', 'abc'): [10, 5, 10, 5.4, 11, 6],
                   ('123', 'efg'): [50, 53, 50, 53, 100, 53],
                   ('456', 'abc'): [10, 5.9, 10, 5.4, 10, 6],
                   ('456', 'efg'): [10, 53, 10, 53, 11, 53]},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.to_datetime(['31-12-2020', '01-01-2021', '02-01-2021']),
                                                                   ['Quantity', 'Price']]).swaplevel()
                 ).T
```

data:

```
          Quantity      Price   Quantity      Price   Quantity      Price
        2020-12-31 2020-12-31 2021-01-01 2021-01-01 2021-02-01 2021-02-01
123 abc       10.0        5.0       10.0        5.4       11.0        6.0
    efg       50.0       53.0       50.0       53.0      100.0       53.0
456 abc       10.0        5.9       10.0        5.4       10.0        6.0
    efg       10.0       53.0       10.0       53.0       11.0       53.0
```

Then you can shift your columns and compute difference:

```
(df-df.shift(2, axis=1)).rename(mapper=lambda x: f'{x}_diff', axis='columns', level=0).dropna(axis=1)
```

output:

```
        Quantity_diff Price_diff Quantity_diff Price_diff
           2021-01-01 2021-01-01    2021-02-01 2021-02-01
123 abc           0.0        0.4           1.0        0.6
    efg           0.0        0.0          50.0        0.0
456 abc           0.0       -0.5           0.0        0.6
    efg           0.0        0.0           1.0        0.0
```

Combined dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df,
           (df-df.shift(2, axis=1)).rename(mapper=lambda x: f'{x}_diff', axis='columns', level=0).dropna(axis=1)
           ], axis=1).sort_index(level=[1,0], ascending=[True, False], axis=1)
```

output:

```
          Quantity      Price Quantity_diff   Quantity Price_diff      Price Quantity_diff   Quantity Price_diff      Price
        2020-12-31 2020-12-31    2021-01-01 2021-01-01 2021-01-01 2021-01-01    2021-02-01 2021-02-01 2021-02-01 2021-02-01
123 abc       10.0        5.0           0.0       10.0        0.4        5.4           1.0       11.0        0.6        6.0
    efg       50.0       53.0           0.0       50.0        0.0       53.0          50.0      100.0        0.0       53.0
456 abc       10.0        5.9           0.0       10.0       -0.5        5.4           0.0       10.0        0.6        6.0
    efg       10.0       53.0           0.0       10.0        0.0       53.0           1.0       11.0        0.0       53.0
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway but unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for.  :(  First I need the new columns to contain 0 when quantity chagnes or cur_Quant*cur_Price - prev_day_Quant * prev_day_Price. Secondly, column names are reliable but order can alter from month to moth as data are exported from a system that produces the columns in radom order.

Comment: Then you should improve your question, unfortunately it is not clear enough to me.